# selector 'nth-last-child(n)' not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
alert($('#Content_tab form .form-group:nth-last-child(2)').html());
```

this and more selection on `nth-last-child(n)` not working in chrome !!

How ever they are working fine in all other browsers, like in IE8, Mozilla.

Please review my [Site](http://pollstudy.suyashkale.com/) and [source code](http://pollstudy.suyashkale.com/js/my_jQuery.js)

> you can find the code near line no. 502

Comment: I don't get any alert on that page. And the code is much too large to investigate. Can you condense the example to the part that is not working, and [post that here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)?

Comment: I can assure you it's not an issue with _Chrome_ or _jQuery_. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/U6arT/) fiddle in _Chrome_. I just made it and ran it in ***Chrome 32.0.1700.72 m***. Open the console with `F12` and you'll see it works fine. If I had to guess, I'd say it's a bad selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
$('#Content_tab form .form-group').eq(-2).html()
```

As a javascript developer, I don't like that selector at all. It is agains my rules to use that kind of selector. It will be very non performant. You can give some class to that element while building your markup or this is even better.

```
$("#Content_tab").find(".form-group").eq(-2).html()
```